# Capture syslog for test cases

Tags: c++, linux, testing, googletest, syslog

I'm writing a command line tool in C++, that - depending on a `--logfile` argument - logs either to `syslog` or to the given file. I would like to test this feature (using `googletest`).

For testing the file part, I run the `MyApp::main()` function with and without the `--logfile` argument and test that log messages appear or don't appear in the file.

Is there a way to test the same for the `syslog`? I could read `/var/log/syslog` and hope for the best, but that wouldn't be very portable, since many systems keep the `syslog` somewhere else.

I'm using a `logging library` that doesn't offer mocking, so that isn't an option. They internally use a call to the `syslog` daemon (`man(3) syslog`). Is there a portable way to get the `syslog` from this daemon? Or from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use library preloading (`LD_PRELOAD`) to cause your program to invoke `syslog` in a library you provide rather than the system `syslog`. Your implementation could then log to a file under your control that you could subsequently check.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using a logging library that doesn't offer mocking,

So at some point you are calling library-function which is writing to the syslog. This is where you're mocking needs to take place. Under X condition library-function get's call once with the following parameters... ext.

Generally I have found in testing when you have a situation where A -> B -> C, Where A is the code you're writing, B is a third party library, and C is the output, you can only test that you are interacting with B appropriately and can't test C.

When using a third party chunk of code, you're essentially trusting it to do what it says it does (unless it's open source and you write tests for their code base).